# How to use boost::iostreams::filtering_wistream to read a gz file in UTF-16LE?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a file `test.txt` written in UTF16-LE, whose contents are as follows:

```
ab
c
```

Now I compressed it with `gz` and got a new file `test.txt.gz`, I want to read this gz file and get the original contents(which is `ab` and `c`).

I decided to use `boost::iostreams::filtering_wistream` to do it. Here is what I've tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
    std::wifstream wInputFileStream("/tmp/test.txt.gz");
    wInputFileStream.imbue(std::locale(wInputFileStream.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<
            wchar_t, 0x10ffff, static_cast<std::codecvt_mode>(std::little_endian | std::consume_header)>));

    boost::iostreams::filtering_wistream wFilteringInputStream;
    wFilteringInputStream.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    wFilteringInputStream.push(wInputFileStream);

    wchar_t c;
    wInputFileStream.get(c); // trying to get the first character in the file, as a test
    std::cout << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work, I got a lot of errors, here are some of them.

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp:22,
                 from /home/searene/CLionProjects/cmake-test/hello.cpp:6:
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/chain.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::iostreams::detail::chain_base<Self, Ch, Tr, Alloc, Mode>::push_impl(const T&, std::streamsize, std::streamsize) [with T = boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<>; Self = boost::iostreams::chain<boost::iostreams::input, wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >; Ch = wchar_t; Tr = std::char_traits<wchar_t>; Alloc = std::allocator<wchar_t>; Mode = boost::iostreams::input; std::streamsize = long int]’:
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/chain.hpp:205:5:   required from ‘void boost::iostreams::detail::chain_base<Self, Ch, Tr, Alloc, Mode>::push(const T&, std::streamsize, std::streamsize, typename boost::disable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<T> >::type*) [with T = boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<>; Self = boost::iostreams::chain<boost::iostreams::input, wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >; Ch = wchar_t; Tr = std::char_traits<wchar_t>; Alloc = std::allocator<wchar_t>; Mode = boost::iostreams::input; std::streamsize = long int; typename boost::disable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<T> >::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/chain.hpp:496:7:   required from ‘void boost::iostreams::detail::chain_client<Chain>::push_impl(const T&, std::streamsize, std::streamsize) [with T = boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<>; Chain = boost::iostreams::chain<boost::iostreams::input, wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >; std::streamsize = long int]’
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/chain.hpp:484:5:   required from ‘void boost::iostreams::detail::chain_client<Chain>::push(const T&, std::streamsize, std::streamsize, typename boost::disable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<T> >::type*) [with T = boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<>; Chain = boost::iostreams::chain<boost::iostreams::input, wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >; std::streamsize = long int; typename boost::disable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<T> >::type = void]’
/home/searene/CLionProjects/cmake-test/hello.cpp:16:69:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/chain.hpp:258:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::list<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >*, std::allocator<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >*> >::push_back(std::unique_ptr<boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<>, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>, boost::iostreams::input>, std::default_delete<boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<>, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>, boost::iostreams::input> > >::pointer)’
         list().push_back(buf.get());
         ^~~~
```

What have I done wrong? How to make it work?

---

About the duplicate:

I've already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934157/using-gzip-compressor-with-boostiostreamsfiltering-wostream-compiler-error), it's different from mine. That question is about how to write, and mine is about how to read. Also, the most important thing is, I cannot hold all the data in a variable when the file I want to read is very large. But for that question, it's not a problem, since it already has a `wstring` that holds all the data. So the answer to that question isn't helpful to me, either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using gzip\_compressor with boost::iostreams::filtering\_wostream, compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934157/using-gzip-compressor-with-boostiostreamsfiltering-wostream-compiler-error)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for providing a relevant question, I just checked it, but it's not a duplicate, I added some texts in the question to explain why.